# alert when object with svg is clicked by id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

I want to do something more complex than this but first I've to detect when an object element that contains a svg image that has an id is clicked, every object is inside a div

```
  <div class=" grid 18"><object data="diente.svg" type="image/svg+xml"id="diente18" ></object></div>
<div class="grid 17"><object data="diente.svg" type="image/svg+xml"id="diente17" ></object></div>
<div class="grid 16"><object data="diente.svg" type="image/svg+xml"id="diente16" ></object></div>
```

this is the jquery code

```
$('object[id^=diente]').on('click', function(){
    alert('selecciono object')
})
```

I don't know if the object inside the click function is invalid or the svg should be contained by another element, I tried to put just 'object' but nothing happened

Comment: you need a space before id i.e. type="image/svg+xml"id="diente18" needs to be type="image/svg+xml" id="diente18"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e8zj3sdf/ this works fine but when I apply into my code where it can detect the svg image and show it nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

The .on method can be a little tricky. Try this.

```
$('div').on('click','object[id^=diente]', function(){
    alert('selecciono object')
})
```

Comment: I tried it but again, nothing, maybe is the object element?

Comment: This should work. You can try it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/e8zj3sdf/

There must be something else going on that's breaking it.